# how to display toaster after routing in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new In angular 4 and I am using ng-toaster to show notification but my notification doesn't work while I am trying to route to another component

here is my sample program

```
  saveData(){
       this.router.navigate(['/home/departmentItemTransfer']);
       this.toaster.warning("Please Add valid data","Opps!");
   }
```

so can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

you just have to put routing code and after in then you have to put your toaster code
 here is sample code that may help you.

```
this.router.navigate(['the state you want to route ']).then(() => {
                        this.toastr.success('your message', 'Success!!', {showCloseButton: true});
                    });
```

if any query please comment

Comment: yes. this will works fine..!! can we make it centralize for each notification ?